# Is it possible to recreate something similar as a Slice for own types?

Tags: rust

One thing about matrix libraries in Rust has always bothered me: There is always a type called something like `MatrixView`, which is related to an owned matrix in the same way as a slice to e.g. a `Vec`. But there is never any `Deref` coercion into the view types, nor are the `AsRef` or `Borrow` traits implemented. I wanted to find out why, and so tried to replicate the `nalgebra` crate myself.

I quickly noticed the issue: All these traits return references, so you cannot just easily create a wrapper struct around a slice or pointer and initialize it in the trait as that would return a reference to a local variable.

My next idea was to create something similar to the slice, so a Dynamically Sized Type, into which I could deref manually via unsafe operations. But I noticed that DSTs are not great to work with. So I thought I could maybe get some inspiration from arrays or vecs. But they use the nightly `ptr_metadata` API to create a wide pointer.

So is it possible to do something like that in stable Rust?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question.. Is all you are asking how to modify a fat pointer in stable rust? That's certainly possible if you are willing to use unsafe. A fat pointer is just two pointers next to each other. Have a look at e.g. [this code](https://docs.rs/smallbox/latest/src/smallbox/smallbox.rs.html#235) (around line 235) from the smallbox crate, which does this.

Comment: I can't speak for `nalgebra`, but a lot of libraries if they already implement `Foo` and `FooView`. Then functions usually don't take `&Foo` nor `&FooView`, but instead they have a `trait GenericFoo`. Where functions then look like e.g. `fn f(foo: impl GenericFoo)`. This is arguably really powerful, as additional types can also `impl GenericFoo`

Comment: If you are fine with heap allocating your matrix, you can do something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05d2e60e0a1ee00aee4ab3d742f806a5). This could be adapted for stack allocated matricies, if you are fine with having a 'wasted' pointer inside of your matrix struct that you always update before handing out the Deref.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very hacky way: I get a fat pointer by casting a `*const [T]` to a pointer to my own wrapper around a slice `*const View<T>` and "abuse" the length of the slice for rows and column information by just using the first and second half of bits, respectively.

```rust
pub struct ViewStorage<T>([T]);

impl<T> ViewStorage<T> {
    pub unsafe fn from_raw_parts<'a>(ptr: *const T, rows: usize, columns: usize) -> &'a Self {
        let size = (rows << 32) + columns;
        let slice = slice_from_raw_parts(ptr, size);
        &*(slice as *const Self)
    }
```

Because this sets the length to a stupidly high value (which allows illegal memory accesses), I need to control every interaction such that the user can never use the underlying slice. My main way is

```rust
    pub fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] {
        let (rows, columns) = self.shape();
        unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(self.1.as_ptr(), rows.dim() * columns.dim()) }
    }

    pub fn as_slice_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [T] {
        let (rows, columns) = self.shape();
        unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.1.as_mut_ptr(), rows.dim() * columns.dim()) }
    }
```

Now, `Deref`, `AsRef`, `Borrow`, and `ToOwned` can be implemented.
In my testings, this works, but I'd be open to better (/ safer) ideas.